# How to configure automated tests to run in different schedules?

Tags: c#, testing, selenium, nunit, teamcity

I have written some system tests using C#, Selenium and NUnit and configured my TeamCity to trigger a build and run all the tests when a code is checked in.

These tests are categorized differently in terms of when to execute; some should run only once a day and the others like every 2 hours.

How this could be achieved?

I thought maybe one solution could be to add Categories and getting TeamCity to run the tests based on the category name e.g. "OneADay", "Every2Hours", "General".

Not sure how to configure TeamCity to identify this.

Or is there any better way to achieve this?

Hope the question is clear.

Many thanks,

Comment: What is the reason for having tests that only run every 2 hours, or once per day? It seems an odd thing to want but I'm guessing that scheduled rather than triggered builds might be the answer

Comment: From what I have seen, scheduled builds allow me to run a build step at a specific time of the day. I couldn't find a setting which allows me distinguish the tests to run in different schedules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of categories on the tests will work. You simply need to specify which categories need to be run by using the **/category-include** and **/category-exclude** parameters of the TeamCity  NUnit test runner.

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/TeamCity+NUnit+Test+Launcher

Comment: Thanks, that was interesting to know. My Build Configuration has one step of running tests where I can include or exclude categories from there. There is another section which can be used to triggering the build but not triggering a step of a Business Configuration. So still not sure how to schedule a configuration step to run. I hoped to be able to schedule running 2 build steps (one to run the "Long" category tests and the other to run the "Frequent" category tests).

Comment: Actually, I created one project with 3 different build configurations. The first build configuration builds the code and the remaining 2 are for running my tests using category-include and category-exclude so they are now scheduled separately :)